# Jquery .getJSON and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
$.getJSON("https://scyk.pl/Account/GetSid").done(function (sid) {
    settings.parameters.sid = sid;
});
```

And this:

```
public JsonResult GetSid()
{
    return Json(SomeString);
}
```

.done function of jquery is not executing - why?

Comment: And how do you know its not executing?

Comment: `settings.parameters.sid` is null, also if I put `console.log("done")`  in there, nothing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the override of `Json` that takes a `JsonRequestBehavior` option and set that to `AllowGet`

```
return Json("string", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To only allow post requests, change your controller action to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetSid()
{
    return Json(SomeString);
}
```

Comment: Then you shouldn't set the request behavior, but of course use jQuery's Ajax method instead of getJson.

Comment: And if you want the restrict requests so that only POST are allowed, add [HttpPost] above the method.